# What can be the reason that oscilloscope is showing voltages 10 times more than expected?

Tags: oscilloscope

I both check via voltmeters and osc. but oscilloscope is showing the values 10 times bigger. For example 5V pulse should be 2.5 mean and voltmeters shows exactly the same but osc. shows 25 V. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like the scope is expecting a 10x probe (which attenuates the signal 10x), but you are using a 1x probe instead, therefore the scope is multiplying the signal by 10 when it shouldn't be.  Check your settings.

Answer (score 11):

Look for the "Probe" settings for your o-scope.  There should be an option to set the probe to a "10x".  Seriously.  It's that straightforward.

Comment: I didn't know such a thing existed.

Comment: @DavidKessner I think you have it backwards -- I think the scope is already set to 10x and he is using a 1x probe, so he either needs to set the scope's 1x/10 setting to 1x, or switch to a 10x probe.